# "Access denied" with "image" package in Rust

Tags: image, rust, filesystems, rust-cargo

I am using this: https://github.com/image-rs/image to create and write to images in Rust. All seems fine, until I save the image with this line of code: `img.save("test.png").unwrap();` I get this error:

`thread 'main' panicked at 'called 'Result::unwrap()' on an 'Err' value: IoError(Os { code: 5, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Access is denied." })'`

And this is literally all of my code:

```rust
let mut img_buf = ImageBuffer::new(new_width.clone().len() as u32, new_height.clone().len() as u32);
img_buf.save("test.png").unwrap(); // Error
```

So what should I do? I've tried to run the program in an admin command prompt and I got the same error.
I'm also running the nightly version of rust because I need it for another feature that I'm using. I'm sorry if there's an obvious answer/solution to it; I am relatively new to rust. Thank you in advance!

Comment: internally this ends up calling [`File::create(path)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create), you can try that directly to see if its somehow `image-rs`'s fault or something else

Comment: The error really means it can't create the file, not necessarily that it is a permission problem. E.g. because the program is executing in a non-writable directory or that the file is already in use and thus can't be truncated.

Comment: @kmdreko When I run `File::create(path)`, it does run successfully, so I'm currently looking through the code to see if there's a problem. Worst case scenario, I can re-create the library, or I could put this error on the `Issues` tab in the GitHub repository.